# CSS Combine Files & Compress

Tags: css, compression

I want to be able to, at build-time, submit a group of CSS files and have the following done:

- Combine all CSS files into one CSS file
- Combine all overlapping selectors
- Remove all comments
- Remove unnecessary white space
- Remove empty styles

I'm sure there are others, but this what I'm starting with.

This is the preference order of how I would like to access the tool:

1. Remote Website
2. Web Hosted Installed - same as my website (Debian/PHP 5.2.12)
3. Local Machine Installed (Windows 7)

I saw [CSS Compressor](http://www.lotterypost.com/css-compress.aspx), but it doesn't seem to combine CSS files nor does it combine overlapping CSS selectors.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's your build tool? It might already have some sort of integration with the [yui compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)

Comment: I'm - at least attempting - to build everything from scratch.  So, no build tool.

Comment: if you're on visual studio, [Cassette](http://getcassette.net/) is a great tool to do exactly what you want. I've been using it for a while now and it rocks!

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/14415721/1991617

I think is what you need

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend the **[YUI compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)** since it is widely used and has a command line interface.

You should also consider making your build process automated so that you can build everything with a single command. If you don't want to use an existing build tool you could create a short `.bat` file for this kind of task.

---

First, combine your files:

```
type file1.css file2.css file3.css > combined.css
```

then pass it to the YUI compressor:

```
java -jar yuicompressor.jar combined.css > combined-min.css
```

Comment: Does YUI Compressor combine all overlapping selectors across multiple files?  I didn't see any options for that.

Comment: [CSS Formatter and Optimiser](http://cdburnerxp.se/cssparse/css_optimiser.php) allows for overlapping selectors.  I doesn't allow (1) multiple files and it (2) hasn't updated since 2007.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Chirpy](http://chirpy.codeplex.com/). It will [combine](http://www.weirdlover.com/2010/07/18/chirpy-attains-godlike-abilities-in-version-1-0-0-4/#mash) and [compress](http://www.weirdlover.com/2010/07/18/chirpy-attains-godlike-abilities-in-version-1-0-0-4/#minify-css) files and v2 has a [command line interface](http://www.weirdlover.com/2011/03/03/chirpy-v2/#console).

I've only ever run it within Visual Studio though.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [sCSSOptimizer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/scssoptimizer/).

- Example

If you want to compile more than one css files than do like this

```
<?php
require('./sCSSOptimizer/scssoptimizer.class.php');

$css1 = file_get_contents("./cssfile1.css");
$css2 = file_get_contents("./cssfile2.css");

$final_css = $css1.$css2; //you can join more, if you want...

$scss = new sCSSOptimizer($final_css);

//$compression_rate = $scss->getCompressionRate();

$compressed_css = $scss->getOptimized();
//do your stuff
?>
```

.